# mySQL query -- if value in string

Tags: mysql

I have a string of IDs separated with comma

```
$myIDs = 22,23,45,895;
```

How do I write a query to return records for values that correspond to the IDs in my string?
This does not seem to be right:

```
SELECT *
FROM t1
WHERE itemID IN ($myIDs)
```

I guess I'm trying PHP array function here, hah? Is there something like this in mySQL?

Appreciate any suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: I can't see a problem there. Are you sure you're interpolating the string correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$IDs = array(1,2,3,4,5);
// alternatively, you can write it like this...
// $IDs = "1,2,3,4,5";

if(is_array($IDs))
    $IDs = implode(",",$IDs);

$query = "SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE itemID IN ($IDs)";
echo $query;
```

Comment: This will create string from array automaticly, array elements are joined automaticaly...  Works both, for arrays of IDs and for a string of IDs as well

Comment: So I would go for this solution... evandrix's solution uses single quotes when comparing INTEGERS, which I think, is not very good idea...

Answer (score 2):

I think you're missing quotes, ie, the exact query should look like this before evaluation

```
SELECT *
FROM t1
WHERE itemID IN ('22','23','45','895');
```

Hence all you've got to do to fix this is:-

```
$myIDs = array(22,23,45,895);
$myIDs_string = "'".implode("','",$myIDs)."'";
```

then in whatever PHP/SQL library/framework you select, use PHP to execute the following php query:-

```
SELECT *
FROM t1
WHERE itemID IN ($myIDs_string);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I would not write IDs like this... '22', since they are numbers, not strings! Or what is their data type in your table?

Comment: oh yea my bad should just remove the quotes in between the values within the implode() argument to @Andreyco's version. sorry